# Android AdMob get Earnings in Code?

Tags: android, admob

Is there a way to Get the Estimated Earnings from Admob in Code for Specific ad Units? Is there a way to access it anywhere from either java code or PHP, SQL? Thank you for your Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AdSense Management API](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/) to get reports on AdSense earnings.

You can make direct requests,or use the [client libraries and samples](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/libraries) for your implementation.

[Here is](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started)  a tutorial on getting started